# What is the plural of peafowl?

Tags: grammatical-number

So, “the peacock’s mission is clear: to create as many baby __ as possible.”

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peafowl) is frustratingly vague on this — it says:

> pea·fowl  [pee-foul]
>  noun, plural pea·fowls (especially collectively) pea·fowl.

So, apparently it could be either *peafowls* or *peafowl*. Any idea which one sounds better or is more respectable?

Comment: You could [let the people decide](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peafowl%2Cpeafowls&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeafowl%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeafowls%3B%2Cc0). (Though I wouldn't have linked to the Ngram if it hadn't supported my preference.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but it's not really a fair fight since (as Ronan mentioned) you have to account for all the instances of singular peafowl.

Comment: Halve the 'peafowl' ordinates for a better guestimate. Or use [these  Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peafowl+are%2Cpeafowls+are%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeafowl%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeafowls%20are%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: You could sidestep the issue by saying "the peacock's mission is clear: to create as many *peachicks* as possible".  (Not that the need is great; it sounds fine and is perfectly clear to say "baby *peafowl*" here.)

Comment: Or just use 'babies'.  If the fellow manages to produce puppies or chickens, more power to him.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, and an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peafowl,%20peafowls&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,peafowl;,c0;.t1;,peafowls;,c0) search shows up a common usage of each, but from my experience, I have head 'fowl' more commonly when referring to many fowl. A similar example would be 'fish'/'fishes'. 'Fish' is the more common plural, so should be used where possible.

(Note on Ngram: Many of these results for 'peafowl' may be referring to singular peafowl, but who has just one?)

Comment: "...but who has just one?" Peafowls: the Lay's Potato Chip of ornithology. (Note: this tongue-in-cheek comment contains an example where I believe using the s-less version would be more awkward/unclear, although I agree that usual use case should be peafowl.)